# Trouble printing a docstring after importing module on command line

Tags: python, module, docstring

I am having trouble printing a docstring after importing it into my terminal window using the python interpreter. After typing python in my terminal window I enter in the following code:

```
import pizza
print(make_pizza.__doc__)
```

The print statement gives me a NameError saying make_pizza is not defined. The pizza module contains the following function:

```
def make_pizza(size, *toppings):
    """Summarize the pizza we are about to make"""
```

When I use the function it works just fine so it must be defined. There is other code for the function, but for simplicity I just want to know how to print the docstring in my terminal window. Any ideas?

Comment: `pizza.make_pizza.__doc__`?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the module name.  Try

```
print(pizza.make_pizza.__doc__)
```